# I've tried to convert it to work with Laravel's DB class except it's not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel-5

I am trying to convert my Sql Query to Laravel Query and I am getting Error :?

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2809 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [2809] (severity 18) [(null)] (SQL: GetRegisteredUserData)

My query1:

```
SELECT * FROM  RegisteredUser WHERE DateCreated between '$startDate' AND  '$endDate' ORDER BY Yr DESC,MnthNo DESC
```

My query2:

```
SELECT * from  UserData where((Yr * 10000 + Mnth * 100 + 1) BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate) ORDER BY Yr Asc, Mnth Asc
```

Comment: Why ((Yr * 10000 + Mnth * 100 + 1) ..??

Comment: strange pseudodate in integer

Comment: @RajeshRanjan In my database structure i have Month and Yr from 2different columns so i am converting to YearMonthDate(Yr * 10000 + Mnth * 100 + 1) . Ex: 20160616

Comment: So the result is 1st June 2016. if at last it would be 16, it will be 16 june 2016 am I right?

Comment: and what is datatype of $startDate and $endDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel 5 we have to do something like this below to execute a query from controller 
$query = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('SELECT * FROM RegisteredUser WHERE((Yr * 10000 + Mnth * 100 + 1) BETWEEN '.$startDate.' AND '.$endDate.')');

$startDate = 20160101 $endDate = 20160601

Answer (score 0):

If $startDate and $endDate are date or datetime.
This query will help you.

```
    SELECT * from  UserData where
    where cast(
    left(cast(yr*10000+mnth*100+day as varchar),4)+'-'+substring(cast(yr*10000+mnth*100+day as varchar),5,2)+'-'+right(cast(yr*10000+mnth*100+day as varchar),2)
    as datetime)
    between $startDate AND $endDate
```

My suggestion is to create a function.

```
    create function fn_returndtae(@yr int,@mnth int,@day)
    returns datetime
    as
    return 
    (
    select
    cast(
            left(cast(@yr*10000+@mnth*100+@day as varchar),4)+'-'+substring(cast(@yr*10000+@mnth*100+@day as varchar),5,2)+'-'+right(cast(@yr*10000+@mnth*100+@day as varchar),2)
            as datetime)
    )
```

And use in WHERE clause.

```
    SELECT * from  UserData where
    where db_name.dbo.fn_returndtae(yr,mnth,day)
    between $startDate AND $endDate
```

Thanks

Comment: Got the Solution :
In laravel we have to do something like this 

$query = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('SELECT * FROM RegisteredUser WHERE((Yr * 10000 + Mnth * 100 + 1) BETWEEN '.$startDate.' AND '.$endDate.')');